# Merge to IList<IWebElement> element into a Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, selenium

I'm trying to create a dictionary from a two IWebelement that I obtain from selenium, the first element is the header of a table and the second one is the value of each column. It's possible to do it?

This are my two Ilist:

```
IList<IWebElement> headersrows = tableheaders.FindElements(By.XPath("tr"));
IList<IWebElement> resultsrows = tableresults.FindElements(By.XPath("tr"));
```

And I do a for to get all the elements from each of the list:

```
    IList<IWebElement> columnsTable;
    foreach (IWebElement row in resultsrows)
    {
        columnsTable = row.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IDictionary<IWebElement, IList<IWebElement>> dict = new Dictionary<IWebElement, IList<IWebElement>>();

int index = 0;
foreach (var header in headersRows.SelectMany(r => r.FindElements(By.XPath("th"))))
{
    dict.Add(header, resultsRows.Select(r => r.FindElements(By.TagName("td"))[index]).ToList());
    index++;
}
```

This will give you a dictionary where the key is the th element, and the values are a list of td elements containing the values for the column.

Comment: Thks a lot that is all that I need. To understand a little: you create a new dictionary that is a merge of an IDictionary and a Ilist, and them using jquery you select for each row all the values by tagname ?

Comment: @FranciscoGonzalez, that's about right. The key is a single header element. The list of column values is retrieved by looking for the TD element at the index of the header column (the values for the 4th header will be in the 4th TD of every row). Selenium offers a way to search elements similar to Jquery, but since it's C# this is of course not actual Jquery.

Comment: Note: this solution has a nested loop: it goes through all the resultsRows multiple times with the Select() function. You could optimize it by looping through the resultsRows first and filling a multidimensional array, then looping through the headerRows and creating the dictionary entries right away. However this may not improve performance by much and would be less readable.